# Building an audio website on React - Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, it's giving me a parsing error in my ternary statements, from the  this.state.isHovered to the end  tag. I know that I have to wrap the statements in curly brackets but am not sure where.

It WAS rendering the code directly onto the page but now I'm getting an error because I think I've structured the ternary statement incorrectly.

Basically, the goal is to have a play icon show up in place of the song number whenever I hover over it.

Have a pause icon show up in place of the song number whenever a song is currently playing and another play icon show up in place of the song number whenever the song is currently paused.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import albumData from './../data/albums';

class Album extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

const album = albumData.find( album => {
  return album.slug === this.props.match.params.slug
});

this.state = {
  album: album,
  currentSong: album.songs[0],
  isPlaying: false
};

this.audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
this.audioElement.src = album.songs[0].audioSrc;
}

play() {
 this.audioElement.play();
 this.setState({ isPlaying: true });
}

pause() {
 this.audioElement.pause();
 this.setState({ isPlaying: false });
}

setSong(song) {
 this.audioElement.src = song.audioSrc;
 this.setState({ currentSong: song });
}

handleSongClick(song) {
 const isSameSong = this.state.currentSong === song;
  if (this.state.isPlaying && isSameSong) {
   this.pause();
 } else {
   if (!isSameSong) { this.setSong(song); }
   this.play();
 }
}

isHovered(song) {
 this.setState({isMouseEnter: song })
};


isNotHovered(song) {
 this.setState({isMouseLeave: null})
};



render() {
 return (
  <section className="album">
  <section id="album-info">
  <img id="album-cover-art" src={this.state.album.albumCover} alt= . 
{this.state.album.title}/>
  <div className="album-details">
  <h1 id="album-title">{this.state.album.title}</h1>
  <h2 className="artist">{this.state.album.artist}</h2>
  <div id="release-info">{this.state.album.releaseInfo}</div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <table id="song-list">
  <colgroup>
  <col id="song-number-column" />
  <col id="song-title-column" />
  <col id="song-duration-column" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
  {this.state.album.songs.map((song, index) =>
    <tr className="song"
      key={index}
        onClick={() => this.handleSongClick(song)}
          onMouseEnter={() => this.isHovered(song)}
            onMouseLeave = {() => this.isNotHovered(song)}>
    <td>
    {(this.state.isHovered === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-play"></span>) :
     (this.state.isPlaying === true && this.state.currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-pause"></span>) :
     (this.state.isPlaying !== true && this.state.currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-play"></span>) }
    </td>
    <td key='number'   > {index + 1}  </td>
    <td key='title'    > {song.title} </td>
    <td key='duration' > {song.duration} </td>

    </tr>
  )}
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </section>
  );
 }
}

export default Album;
```

Comment: can you add the error as well ?

Comment: Your final line in the ternary does not have an `:` (*`else`*)

Answer (score 1):

your last ternary condition is missing the else condition.
Use either of the following:

```
{(this.state.isHovered === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-play"></span>) :
     (this.state.isPlaying === true && this.state.currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-pause"></span>) :
     (this.state.isPlaying !== true && this.state.currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-play"></span>) : null }
```

or

```
{(this.state.isHovered === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-play"></span>) :
     (this.state.isPlaying === true && this.state.currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-pause"></span>) :
     (this.state.isPlaying !== true && this.state.currentSong === song) && (<span className="ion-md-play"></span>) }
```

also it is better to extract such complex logic into a function on the component and return the value that is suited. This will not pass the eslint or linting standard for JS.

Comment: Appreciate the input and your solutions worked. I'm not sure what you mean by extracting the function on the component and returning the value

Comment: I'm also trying to get the icons to show up on hover, but nothing is popping up whenever I hover over the song number

Comment: Do you know how to upload screenshots? I'm trying to show the webpage or errors